# Describe the image of a complex function defined by line integral.

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, conformal-geometry, mobius-transformation

Let $\mathbb{H}$ be the upper half plane in $\mathbb C$.

I was asked to describe the image of the function $f:\mathbb{H}\to \mathbb{C}$ defined by:
$$f(z)=\int_{i}^z\frac{dw}{(w-1)^a(w+1)
^b}$$
where $a,b \in (0,1)$ and $a+b<1$.

**Note**: This is from a past graduate exam so I don't know what is the relevant background to solve this.

Comment: Looks like a [Schwarz–Christoffel mapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz–Christoffel_mapping)

Comment: $\mathbb H$ is quaternions?

Comment: @BCLC Context. Upper half-plane in $\Bbb C$.

Comment: @TedShifrin excluding axis because is including is denoted by $\overline{\mathbb{H}}$ ?

Comment: @MartinR what's the answer if it's $\mathbb C$ instead of $\mathbb H$? anyhoo i made your comment nto communitywiki. you can answer if you want and then i would award you the bounty

Comment: @TedShifrin why don't you answer and then i award you bounty?